# Dropdown list is empty

Tags: php, mysql

My dropdown list shows empty. I am not sure if my query returns any records. How can I find out if my query returned any result? Here is my code. Please let me know. I am stuck with this issue.

```
 <?php $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root"); 
            if (!$link) {     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } 
            echo 'Connected successfully'; 

                mysql_select_db("mydb");  
                $sql = "SELECT state_id, state_code FROM states"; 
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                ?>

 <p>  
<select name="vers">  
 <?  

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
   echo "<option value=\"".$row['state_id']."\">".$row["state_code"]."</option>";   
 }  
 ?>  
 </select>

<?
            mysql_close($link); 
            ?>
```

Comment: *Please* don't use the `root` user in a production environment...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am going to use 'root' on production. This is just dev machine.

Comment: And _please_ escape your output!

Comment: The same goes for default passwords or passwords as simple as 'root'.

Comment: And it is better to separate your settings and code. If you place login, password, db name on the other file, you will able to include it in all *.php files of your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test the success or failure of your query with `if (!$result)` and use `mysql_num_rows()` to verify the number of rows returned.  Rather than `die()`, you can display a better error to your user and possibly render different HTML, rather than just exit the script abruptly.

```
  mysql_select_db("mydb");  
  $sql = "SELECT state_id, state_code FROM states"; 
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  // Instead of die(), use a construct like this for better error handling on your page
  if (!$result) {
    // query error
  }     

  if (mysql_num_rows($result) === 0) {
    // No rows returned
  }
  else {
    // Success! Populate your <select> with <option>s
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
     echo "<option value=\"".$row['state_id']."\">".$row["state_code"]."</option>";   
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Add an empty default option. Make sure its `value` attribute is not something you would retrieve from your database.

```
<select name="vers"> 
  <option value='-1'>Choose an option...</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It did return 50 records. But I am not sure why the dropdown list shows empty.

Comment: @nav100 Do you have PHP's `short_open_tag` enabled? You start that block with `<?` instead of `<?php`. View your page source.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. How can I add an empty item(default) on the top of the list?

Comment: @nav100 Just add a dummy option right beneath the opening `<select>` tag. See above.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query directly against the database using a tool such as [MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

```
SELECT state_id, state_code FROM states
```

I suspect there are no results.

UPDATE: Given that 50 results are expected... can you try this version with minor updates and report back on any warnings or errors you can see.

```
<?php
use error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // Development use only!

$link = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "root") or die ('Error connecting to mysql' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("mydb");  

$sql = "SELECT state_id, state_code FROM states;"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<p>  
    <select name="vers">  
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<option value="' . $row['state_id'] . '">' . $row['state_code']  . '</option>';
    }  
    ?>  
    </select>
</p>
<?php
mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

Comment: There are 50 records when I run against the database.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find out if my query returned any result?

Run your query on your Database Server instead of through PHP and see if it returns any results.  If you use shared hosting with MySQL, many hosts provide a phpmyadmin interface that lets you run SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) to find out how many elements you have in your `$result`

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should  check your table "states". If it is empty, your code is correct. For example, you can use PhpMyAdmin - http://www.phpmyadmin.net. Execute your query with phpMyAdmin